# Can window functions navigate through and conditionally select specific rows in an ordered BigQuery rowset?

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a BigQuery result set, containing website events, which can be grouped and sorted along several columns including timestamp and event type and userId.

For each userId I would like to return the first row by timestamp of `event_type_1` (sign-in), then for the same user return the first row of `event_type_2` (pageView) but only if `event_type_2.timestamp` >= `event_type_1.timestamp`. Repeat for a half-dozen event types and return the results for all users.

I know I can accomplish this using named subqueries, e.g. the WITH clause, as shown in the following example. But that's inefficient since it runs the subquery on each reference to it. The subquery inside the WITH statement runs in about 5 seconds, while the entire query takes a multiple of 5 seconds depending on how many times the subquery is referenced.

```
WITH filtered_events AS 
    (
    SELECT * FROM per_user_events ORDER BY userId, timestamp -- note: this is vastly simplified
  ),
event_type_1 as (
  SELECT *
  FROM filtered_events
  WHERE filtered_events.type = 1),
event_type_2 as (
  SELECT filtered_events.*
  FROM filtered_events
    INNER JOIN event_type_1 ON event_type_1.userId = filtered_events.userId
  WHERE filtered_events.type = 2
  AND filtered_events.timestamp >= event_type_1.timestamp),
event_type_3 as (
  SELECT filtered_events.*
  FROM filtered_events
    INNER JOIN event_type_2 ON event_type_2.userId = filtered_events.userId
  WHERE filtered_events.type = 3
  AND filtered_events.timestamp >= event_type_2.timestamp),
event_type_4 as (
  SELECT filtered_events.*
  FROM filtered_events
    INNER JOIN event_type_3 ON event_type_3.userId = filtered_events.userId
  WHERE filtered_events.type = 4
  AND filtered_events.timestamp >= event_type_3.timestamp)
SELECT * FROM event_type_1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM event_type_2
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM event_type_3
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM event_type_4
ORDER BY userId, timestamp
```

I know I can materialize the subquery as a temporary or permanent BQ table if my only goal is faster queries / less resources. But I'm wondering if window functions can (on a per-user basis) locate the first `event_type_1` by timestamp, then find the first `event_type_2` which comes *after* timestamp1, then the first `event_type_3` coming after timestamp2, etc.

I am familiar with using the window function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY)` to select a subset of rows per event, but this doesn't help me to skip past instances of event2 which come *before* event1, and therefore end up with the desired sequencing of event1 --> event2 --> event3 on a per-user basis.

Comment: is following filter `filtered_events.timestamp >= event_type_1.timestamp` applicable for all events or previous event should be involved?

Comment: Great question. If I would complete the `WITH() as` subquery for `event_type_3`, it only needs to check that it happens after `event_type_2`. That's because event_type_2 already has a WHERE clause that requires that it happens after event_type_1.

In general if there are N events, and each one must follow the one before it, the WHERE clause for event N can have 1 timestamp check (not N-1)

Comment: referencing `not` in `(not N-1)` is quite confusing - you might wanted to say `(for N-1)` - can you clarify?

Comment: In general if there are N events, and each one must follow the one before it, the WHERE clause for event N can have 1 timestamp check, rather than (N-1). I have edited the pseudocode in the original post to reflect this.

Comment: it is clear now - after you updated the question :o)